# Similar Word Finder

Tags: java

**Similar Word Finder**

I created this similar word finder for fun.
(word.txt are words from http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt)
Is there any way to make this better or more accurate?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Main {

    public static void print(String text, int times) {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            System.out.print(text);
        }

    }
    public static void println(String text, int times) {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("word.txt"));
            

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                arrayList.add(line);
            }
            println("Welcome to similar word finder. This program searches ​58100 different words for words that are similar to the word that you entered",1);
            print("Enter a word: ", 1);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String checkWord = scanner.nextLine();
                        for (int i = 0; i < checkWord.length(); i++) {
                                // checks whether the character is not a letter
                                // if it is not a letter ,it will return false
                                if ((Character.isLetter(checkWord.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                                    println("Your word contains a not-unicode letter!",1);
                                    System.exit(1);
                                }
                        }
                        ArrayList<String> similarwords = new ArrayList<>();
                        print("How strict do you want the search to be? (1) Very Strict (2) Normal strict (3) Not very strict: ",1);
                        String strict = scanner.nextLine();
            //println(arrayList.toString(),1);
            int minus = 0;
                        if (strict == "1") {
                            minus = 1;
                        } else {
                            if (strict=="2") {
                                minus = 2;
                            } else {
                                if (strict=="3") {
                                    minus = 3;
                                
                                } else {
                                    minus =2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
            int timesRight = 0;
            int timesRight2 = 0;
            if (checkWord.length() > 3) {
                  timesRight2 = checkWord.length()-minus;
                                        println("Similar Words:", 1);
            } else {
                            if (checkWord.length() > 2) {
                                timesRight2=checkWord.length();
                            }else {
                                timesRight=2;
                            }
                  
            }
            checkWord = checkWord.trim();                
            try {
                  String[] letters = checkWord.split("");
                                
                  for (String word3 : arrayList) {
                                    
                        timesRight=0;
                        String[] letters2 = word3.split("");
                        int under = 0;
                        if (letters.length<=letters2.length) {
                                under = letters.length;
                        } else {
                                under = letters2.length;
                        }
                        for(int i = 0; i < under;i++) {
                                    
                                    if (letters2[i].equals(letters[i])) {
                                timesRight++;
                                                
                          } else {
                              if(i<letters2.length-2 && i<letters.length-2){
                                  if (letters2[i+1].equals(letters[i])) {
                                        timesRight++;
                                                        
                                                    
                                  }
                              }
                                                
                            }
                        } 

                        if (timesRight>timesRight2) {
                                                    if 
                                                    if (word3 != checkWord) {
                                                            //System.out.println(checkWord);
                                                        similarwords.add(word3);
                              println(word3 +" #" + similarwords.size() , 1);
                                                    }else {
                                                        println(word3 + " (search word)",1);
                                                    }
                                            
                        } else {
                                                    //println("x",1);
                                                }
                  }
                                    
                                    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Error!: " + e);
                                
            }
                           
                        
                                                      
                            

                    
                
                

            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your word match to be more accurate, look up Soundex matching.

I worked on making your code more readable by ordinary humans.

I couldn't figure out how you were matching words.  I made an assumption that you were selecting words based on a count of the letter differences.

Generally, when you write a Java class, it should read like an essay.  The most important information is at the beginning, and as you go further down the code, you see more and more details.  Details that are presented in bite-size morsels that we call methods.

Almost all of your code was in one main method.  Your code was hard for me to follow, and as I said, I gave up trying to figure out how you were comparing words and just wrote my own code.

Here's the primary method I wrote to find similar words.

```
public void findSimilarWords() {
    List<String> wordList = readWordList();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String checkword = readWord(scanner);
    int level = readStrictLevel(scanner);
    List<String> matchingWords = findMatchingWords(
            wordList, checkword, level);
    createOutput(checkword, matchingWords);
    scanner.close();
}
```

Seven lines of code.  Now, at this point, we don't know the details.  We know there's a word list, that we get a word and a match level from the console, and we output matching words.  At this point, that's all we need to know.

We'll get the details as we read further down the class code.

I think I've made my point.  Here's the revised code.  I hope you find this code easier to understand and more importantly, easier to modify.  Code is not just for computers.  Humans have to read and understand the code as well.  Including you after time has passed.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimilarWordFinder {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimilarWordFinder swf = new SimilarWordFinder();
        swf.findSimilarWords();
    }

    public void findSimilarWords() {
        List<String> wordList = readWordList();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String checkword = readWord(scanner);
        int level = readStrictLevel(scanner);
        List<String> matchingWords = findMatchingWords(
                wordList, checkword, level);
        createOutput(checkword, matchingWords);
        scanner.close();
    }
    
    private List<String> readWordList() {
        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.mieliestronk.com/"
                    + "corncob_lowercase.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                wordList.add(line.trim());
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return wordList;
    }
    
    private String readWord(Scanner scanner) {
        println("Welcome to similar word finder. This program "
                + "searches ​58,100 different words for words that "
                + "are similar to the word that you entered",
                1);
        boolean invalidWord = true;
        String checkWord  = "";
        
        while (invalidWord) {
            print("Enter a word: ", 1);
            checkWord = scanner.nextLine();
            invalidWord = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < checkWord.length(); i++) {
                // checks whether the character is not a letter
                // if it is not a letter ,it will return false
                if (!Character.isLetter(checkWord.charAt(i))) {
                    println("Your word contains a not-unicode letter!", 1);
                    invalidWord = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return checkWord;
    }
    
    private int readStrictLevel(Scanner scanner) {
        print("How strict do you want the search to be? (1) Very "
                + "Strict (2) Normal strict (3) Not very strict: ",
                1);
        String strict = scanner.nextLine();
        return valueOf(strict);
    }
    
    private List<String> findMatchingWords(List<String> wordList,
            String word, int level) {
        List<String> similarWords = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (String matchWord : wordList) {
            if (matchWord.length() == word.length()) {
                int difference = calculateWordDifference(word, matchWord);
                if (difference <= level) {
                    similarWords.add(matchWord);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return similarWords;
    }
    
    private int calculateWordDifference(String word, String matchWord) {
        int difference = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) != matchWord.charAt(i)) {
                difference++;
            }
        }
        
        return difference;
    }
    
    private void createOutput(String word, List<String> matchingWords) {
        println(" ", 1);
        println("The following words match \"" + word + "\"", 1);
        println(" ", 1);
        
        for (String matchingWord : matchingWords) {
            println("    " + matchingWord, 1);
        }
    }
    
    private void print(String text, int times) {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            System.out.print(text);
        }
    }

    private void println(String text, int times) {
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
    
    private int valueOf(String number) {
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(number);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    
}
```